# Unable to build GWT project in NetBeans

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, maven, netbeans

I have a maven-based GWT project *(GWTApplication)* which includes two java libraries (which are also maven-based) - *entity* and *metadata*.

Entity's pom.xml:

```
<groupId>com.gfa.gwt</groupId>
<artifactId>gwt-entity</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>0.1</version>
```

Metadata's pom.xml:

```
<groupId>com.gfa.gwt</groupId>
<artifactId>gwt-metadata</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>0.1</version>
```

Main project's pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>com.gfa.gwt</groupId>
  <artifactId>gwt-metadata</artifactId>
  <version>0.1</version>
 </dependency>

 <dependency>
  <groupId>com.gfa.gwt</groupId>
  <artifactId>gwt-entity</artifactId>
  <version>0.1</version>
 </dependency>
...
</dependencies>
```

When I try to compile this project (clean and build) output shows errors:

> Compiling module test.application.Application    Validating newly
>   compiled units
>         Ignored 42 units with compilation errors in first pass. Compile with -strict or with -logLevel set to TRACE or DEBUG to see all
>   errors.    Finding entry point classes
>         [ERROR] Errors in 'file:~/workspace/GwtApplication/src/main/java/test/application/client/ApplicationPoint.java'
>            [ERROR] Line 97: No source code is available for type com.gfa.gwt.entity.shared.InstancesLookuper; did you forget to inherit
>   a required module?
>            [ERROR] Line 97: No source code is available for type com.gfa.gwt.metadata.client.MetaDataApi; did you forget to inherit a
>   required module?
>         [ERROR] Unable to find type 'test.application.client.ApplicationPoint'
>            [ERROR] Hint: Previous compiler errors may have made this type unavailable
>            [ERROR] Hint: Check the inheritance chain from your module; it may not be inheriting a required module or a module may not be
>   adding its source path entries properly Exception in thread
>   "UnitWriteThread" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to read from byte
>   cache     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.util.DiskCache.transferToStream(DiskCache.java:196)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.util.DiskCacheToken.writeObject(DiskCacheToken.java:91)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor22.invoke(Unknown Source)     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)     at
>   java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:962)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1480)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1528)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1493)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1416)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
>     at
>   java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.javac.PersistentUnitCache$UnitWriter.run(PersistentUnitCache.java:226)
>   Caused by: java.io.IOException: Stream Closed     at
>   java.io.RandomAccessFile.seek(Native Method)  at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.util.DiskCache.transferToStream(DiskCache.java:182)
>     ... 14 more

Of course I have inherited these modules in *.gwt.xml file:

```
<inherits name="com.gfa.gwt.metadata.MetaData"/>
<inherits name="com.gfa.gwt.entity.Entity"/>
```

In eclipse this project compiles with no problems, but in NetBeans during compilation I see those errors. Did I miss something?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should to include java classes to your `gwt-metadata` jar file. Add to pom (gwt-metadata):

```
<build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/client/**</include>
                    <include>**/shared/**</include>
                    <include>**/*.gwt.xml</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
```

or

```
<plugins>
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

Comment: Thanks. I have tried your second option, but it didn't work. First works OK. And finally, why NetBeans didn't see sources and Eclipse saw them?